# Prove a piecewise function is differentiable at $ x = 1 $

Tags: limits, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

Use the difference quotient definition of the derivative,
$$ f ' ( a ) = \lim _ { x \to a } \frac { f ( x ) - f ( a ) } { x - a } \text , $$
to show that
$$ f ( x ) = \begin {cases}
x \ln x \text , & x \le 1 \\
x - 1 \text , & x > 1
\end {cases} $$
is differentiable at $ x = 1 $.

Comment: please tell us what you tried, since the question clearly states what you should do.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that on the one hand
$$
f'_{+}(a)
=\lim_{x\to1^{+}}\frac{\overbrace{f(x)}^{x-1}-\overbrace{f(1)}^{0}}{x-1}
=\lim_{x\to1^{+}}\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1
$$
On the other hand
$$
\begin{split}
f'_{-}(a)
&=\lim_{x\to1^{-}}\frac{\overbrace{f(x)}^{x\ln x}-\overbrace{f(1)}^{0}}{x-1}
=\lim_{x\to1^{-}}\frac{x\ln x}{x-1}\\
&\overset{\small t=x-1}{=}
\lim_{t\to0^{-}}\frac{(t+1)\ln(t+1)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^{-}}(t+1)\lim_{t\to0^{-}}\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t}\\
&=1\cdot(0+1)=1
\end{split}
$$
Therefore, $f'_{+}(1)=f'_{-}(1)$, so $f'(1)=1$, as required.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Can I please ask what happened with the t at the bottom in the second last step?

Comment: what do you mean? I applied limit arithmetic and used the well known limit $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1$$